# Constructor called at wrong time

Tags: c++, oop, opengl, constructor, segmentation-fault

This is less of a plea for help over a problem, and more of a question about something peculiar discovered after solving a problem. I was working on my beginner OpenGL game and was attempting to write an OOP friendly rendering file. All vbo data was being stored in a model class, where it was uploaded and buffered in the constructor.

Vastly simplified structure of this from main would look something like:

```
int main(){
    vector <Model> Models;

    Graphics.GLInit();

    Models.push_back(Model(vertices,texcoords,36,0));

    Graphics.EnableAttributePointers();

    main loop
    {
        Graphics.draw(Models,Textures,Entities);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Constructor looked like:

```
Model::Model(vector <vec3> &vertices,vector <vec2> &texcoords,int NumVertices,int StartVertex)
{
    iNumVertices=NumVertices;
    iStartVertex=StartVertex;

    Vertices=vertices;
    Texcoords=texcoords;

    glGenBuffers(1,&vboVertex);
    glGenBuffers(1,&vboTexcoord);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboVertex);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Vertices.size()*12,Vertices.data(),GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboTexcoord);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,TexCoord.size()*8,TexCoord.data(),GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Upon calling glDrawArrays in the drawing function a segmentation fault would occur:

```
0xC0000005 cannot access 0x00000000 yadda yadda.
```

So I checked over everything countless times, making sure it all made sense. Eventually I tore apart the program, making a simpler version in which the same exact code is being used without a model class. That worked fine. Figuring something was wrong with the Model class, I eventually placed the buffering code into a separate function to be called directly after the constructor. This fixed it.

Anyways, all this begs the question of why the constructor was seemingly being called upon out of sequence; before the GLInit code. That, or there is some behavioral quirk of constructors which I am unaware of, wherein the OpenGL state machine cannot be properly modified by them for some bizarre reason. My knowledge of C++ is only spare time highschooler level, so am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Where is `Models.push_back(Model(vertices,texcoords,36,0));` called? According to your code it's just outside any scope so it wouldn't compile.

Comment: All of that code is executing in main. "vastly simplified structure of this from <bold>main</bold>..." Anyways, edited it to be more clear.

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE?

Comment: Are you certain that `Model` is rule-of-five compliant and won't do anything silly on, e.g., vector reallocation?

Comment: I've put together a 170 line SSCCE although it actually works... annoyingly. It may be difficult to emulate the problem in a simple manner.

Comment: if you don't compile this with a c++11 compliant compiler, your member `Vertices` data will be copied instead of its pointer being moved. `push_back` = "call my copy ctor" for pre c++11.

Comment: I'm using VC2010 express (v100). It seems to support some but not all C++11 features.

Comment: @UncleCrusty AFAIK VS 2010 does not support automatic generation of move ctors/move assignments. If you define a move ctor and move assignment and disable copy ctor/copy assignment (http://tinyurl.com/n6lc8dh) then it should be fine. Otherwise not only the item being pushed back but also the contents of the vector will be copied when capacity is exceeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am thinking since you are creating vector of Model, the following code

`Models.push_back(Model(vertices,texcoords,36,0));`

actually makes a COPY (copy constructor will be called) pushes the copy into the vector. Then the original is deleted.

It would be interesting to see the actual data members of class Model and also what is the datatype of "vec3" and "vec2"?

Can we see the destructor function also?

Comment: It looks like Vertices and Texcoords are data members of class Model and are of vector type. It would be good to see the destructor and data members of the classes involved. Anyway, I am only guessing maybe a double delete happened. I will edit the answer to remove double delete.

Comment: @Purrfection: Even if that is not the case, the destructor may be calling `glDeleteBuffers (...)`. While the copy in the `std::vector` is blissfully unaware that the OpenGL data store for which its vertex array pointers are relative to no longer exists. Definitely need to see the dtor in this case.

Comment: @anonymous: my guess as well, a typical issue of double-free induced by a shallow copy constructor.